# $.get does not work in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, datepicker

Clicking a date in datepicker doesnt do anything?  It should get data from getdata.php, i dont know if the request is sent or not but nothing gets updated in the div #events

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var dates = [<?= $dates; ?>];

$(function(){

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
numberOfMonths: [1,1],
beforeShowDay: highlightDays
});


$('#datepicker').click(function(){
// put your selected date into the data object
var data = $('#datepicker').val();


$.get('/getdata.php?date='+ encodeURIComponent(data), function(data) {
$('#events').empty();
$('#events').html(data).show('slow');
});
});

function highlightDays(date) {
for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
if (dates[i].getTime() == date.getTime()) {
return [true, 'highlight'];
}
}
return [true, ''];

}  

});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you include the jQuery library?

Comment: Where is it failing? Does the request get sent? Does the request come back? Use some kind of client side debugging tool (a la firebug) to provide more information. If it's only in IE, what browsers are working?

Comment: Maybe check out your olderquestions and accept answers or if there are none, try to add your own sollution?

Comment: i dont know if the request gets sent but nothing comes back the div #events doesnt change and it should return data from the getdata.php file

Comment: see the full <script> tag now that i added

Comment: yes the jquery library is included.  This works in FF safari just not in IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you wrap all your JS in:

```
$(function() {

 // code goes here

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the prevent default from evt??
I had a problem like that

```
$('#datepicker').click(function(evt){
// put your selected date into the data object
var data = $('#datepicker').val();
$.get('/getdata.php?date='+data, function(data) {
$('#events').empty();
$('#events').html(data).show('slow');
evt.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try 
'/getdata.php?date='+ encodeURIComponent(data) 
instead of 
'/getdata.php?date='+ data